# question on serialization and deserialization in binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, binary, binary-tree

There is this problem asked by Google to design an algorithim to serialize and deserialize binary tree. I found one of the solutions online. The part i don't really understand is why the condition is necessary at line 20, where "if node == None:", self.root = Node(value) ? Because afterall this program will prompt the user to input nodes in the form eg: 1,3,5 in order for the program to work so therefore there won't be a case where node =none because user input is necessary? Am I misunderstanding something else here?

[image]

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value

class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addNode(self, node, value): #Why when node==None, self.root= Node(value)?
        if node == None:
            self.root = Node(value)
        else:
            if value < node.value:
                if not node.left:
                    node.left = Node(value)
                else:
                    self.addNode(node.left, value)
            else:
                if not node.right:
                    node.right = Node(value)
                else:
                    self.addNode(node.right, value)


def serialize(root):
    values = []
    def serializer(node):
        if not node:
            values.append('?')
        else:
            values.append(str(node.value))
            serializer(node.left)
            serializer(node.right)
    serializer(root)
    return ','.join(values)

def deserialize(s):
    values = iter(s.split(','))
    def deserializer():
        val = next(values)
        if val == '?':
            return None
        else:
            node = Node(int(val))
            node.left = deserializer()
            node.right = deserializer()
            return node
    return deserializer()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Read input, numbers separated by commas
    numbers = [int(n) for n in input().split(',')]
    theTree = Tree()
    for number in numbers:
        theTree.addNode(theTree.root, number)
    s1 = serialize(theTree.root)
    s2 = serialize(deserialize(s1))
    print(s1) 
    print(s2)
    assert s1 == s2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line, when first number is entered in the tree, root will be None

```
for number in numbers:
    theTree.addNode(theTree.root, number)
```

Hence, line 20 is needed.

Comment: why "when first number is entered in the tree, root will be None"?

Comment: Is it because  of class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None ?

Comment: Yes when the tree is initialised, self.root = None

Comment: alright i see, but after that wouldn't the else part be neglected? Like in what situation, will the else part in line 21 be considered?

Comment: Also what does self.root = Node(value) in line 20 means here?

Comment: It means, code is creating a new Node of the tree (fresh node) in this case root node. Else part will be used whenever the root is not None or tree has at least 1 node.

Comment: so the node here is represented by the numbers that i have input? Like 1,5,4,6 for example? So 1 is the root node that will go throught the self.root=Node(value) while the rest 5,4,6 will go through the else part?

Comment: Yes value of nodes will be the input numbers. Yes 1 in this case will be root node and rest of the input numbers will go through else part.